# How does the sort() work in javascript?

Tags: javascript, sorting

```
var numArray = [4,2,5,3];
numArray.sort(function(a,b){
  console.log("a:" + a + ", b:" + b);
  return a-b;
});
```

The three possible return numbers are: <0 (less than 0), 0, or >0 (greater than 0):

```
 Less than 0: Sort "a" to be a lower index than "b"
 Zero: "a" and "b" should be considered equal, and no sorting performed.
 Greater than 0: Sort "b" to be a lower index than "a".
```

I am getting like this on console

```
    a:4, b:2
    a:4, b:5
    a:5, b:3
    a:2, b:3
    a:4, b:3
    [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

May I know how the values of a and b are getting changed as seen above?

> In the first step 
>      a=4 and b=2. In this case it will swap.
>      then the array becomes [2,4,5,3];
>
> In the second step 
>      a=4 and b=5. In this case the items remains same.
>      then the array becomes [2,4,5,3];
>
> In the third step 
>      a=5 and b=3. In this case it will swap.
>      then the array becomes [2,4,3,5];
>
> Until this step it is okay. But after that how the value of a and b becomes 2 and 3 >    respectively instead of 2 and 4.

Anyone can help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This probably depends on the browser. Which browser are you using?

Comment: Array sort uses whatever algorithm it wants. You are expecting a simple bubble sort, but it doesn't have to do that. Your function is used only as the basis of comparison of values.

Comment: Mark: I have checked this in 2 browsers firefox and chrome. The result is same

Comment: RobG: If it is comparison of value after third step how the value of and b changes to 2 and 3 instead of 2 and 4.

Comment: Because it isn't doing a simple bubble sort. Perhaps someone who knows more than me about sort algorithms (pretty much anyone!) can identify which one is being used.

Comment: Well, which one is used is very likely irrelevant. They should look at what the specification guarantees (apart from a sorted result sequence), e.g. stability and not make any assumptions beyond that.

Comment: The algorithm might also vary depending on the array size.

Comment: @katspaugh : do you know which algorithm is used for the array mentioned above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no guarantee that the sort method uses a simple compare and swap algorithm.

More likely your browser uses something like [merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort), but the specific algorithm will depend on the browser and version.

Since Firefox is open source you can see how sort is implemented by checking the [source code](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla/source/js/src/jsarray.c). It uses a merge sort.

Comment: @Joey: I wouldn't say that merging is simple swapping. Obviously the result is that the data is swapped at the end, but the steps to get there can be more complicated than just simply swapping elements in-place.

Comment: Hm, you're right. Conceptually I just quickly thought about Quicksort, Heapsort and the n² ones but somehow ignored Mergesort.